# Typescript: Define type for object param of arrow function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to define the type for object parameter in a arrow function, i'm new in typescript and i did find any exemple showing this case.
so:

```
    const audioElem = Array.from(videoElem.parentNode.childNodes).find(
      (child: {tagName: string}): boolean => child.tagName === 'AUDIO',
    );
```

I'm just getting an error and that's normal but you got the idea.
Any idea ? :)

Error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(child: { tagName: string; }) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: {}, index: number, obj: {}[]) => boolean'.
  Types of parameters 'child' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Property 'tagName' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ tagName: string; }'.

17       (child: { tagName: string }): boolean => child.tagName === 'AUDIO',
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/components/Subscriber/Subscriber.tsx:17:17
    17       (child: { tagName: string }): boolean => child.tagName === 'AUDIO',
                       ~~~~~~~
    'tagName' is declared here.
```

Comment: *What* error? It looks fine in e.g. http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20videoElem%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20audioElem%20%3D%20Array.from(videoElem.parentNode.childNodes).find(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20(child%3A%20%7BtagName%3A%20string%7D)%3A%20boolean%20%3D%3E%20child.tagName%20%3D%3D%3D%20'AUDIO'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0D%0A

Comment: I'm getting this error with `tsc --watch`: https://pastebin.com/MH6PkC7g

Comment: Do *not* put images of code or errors. *Do* paste *text* of code and errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `type` of `interface` to do that.

```
// Either…
type MyParam = {
  tagName: string
}

// … or…
interface MyParam {
  tagName: string
}

// …and then.
const audioElem = Array.from(videoElem.parentNode.childNodes).find(
  (child: MyParam): boolean => child.tagName === 'AUDIO',
);
```

As for the difference between the two, you can read [this article](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/interface-vs-type-alias-in-typescript-2-7-2a8f1777af4c).

Comment: I tried too but i'm still getting an error like that: https://pastebin.com/MH6PkC7g